# visualizing output in ggplotly: from the table to the plot

Tags: r, ggplotly

I have a table and a plot done using `ggplotly`. The table is in `DT::datatable` format. When I zoom into the plot, the values that are within the frame in the plot become visible in my table. My question is, is it possible to visualize the only point in the plot when I click on a certain row of the table? if so, how?